# How to create a serializer for decimal in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a Company model from json API.
This is the code for it.

#### company.dart

```
import 'dart:convert' as json;
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';
import 'serializers.dart';
part 'company.g.dart';

abstract class Company implements Built<Company, CompanyBuilder> {
  static Serializer<Company> get serializer => _$companySerializer;
  int get code;
  @nullable
  String get name;
  @nullable
  Decimal get price;
  Company._();
  factory Company([updates(CompanyBuilder b)]) = _$Company;
}
```

When I use `int get price` instead of `Decimal get price`, the code works fine. (Of course I also need to change server side code.)

This code fails with this error.

```
Deserializing '[code, 1000, name, company_name, price: 100.0, ...' to 'Company' failed due to: Bad state: No serializer for 'Decimal'.
```

The serializer is created by the commend `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`.
Probably I need to tell the serializer how to treat `Decimal`, but I don't know how.

This is `serializers.dart`.

```
library serializers;
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';
import 'company.dart';
part 'serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor(const [Company])
final Serializers serializers = _$serializers;
Serializers standardSerializers =
    (serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(new StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

How should I change the code?

Comment: why just don’t use `num`?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know `num` type. I'll use `num` this time, but I'll keep the question open. Because sometimes I need to avoid float rounding errors.